# Anylogic Experiment stuck using varied in range parameter but works fine in freeform parameters

Tags: java, simulation, montecarlo, anylogic

I am trying to run an experiment with two varied parameters.

The experiment will run well if I choose to vary the parameter in freeform, e.g. `surgeLevel: uniform(2,5), surgeDuration: uniform(20,60)`. However, if I use varied in range parameter variation, e.g. `surge Level: min(2),max(5),step(0.1), surgeDuration: min(20),max(60),step(1)`, the experiment will not even be able to finish 1 round of simulation. Does anyone know how to make the experiment run smoothly with varied in range parameters?

I am trying to generate four datasets using my root model outputs for the experiment. 
[experiment java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXHtf.jpg)

a screenshot of my [freeform parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IICh.jpg)
a screenshot of my [varied in range parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDrK5.jpg)

The experiment runs very well if I use the freeform option, but will be extremely slow if I choose the varied in range option for reasons I cannot figure out. I will prefer to run in the varied in range format since it will allow me compare different condition under fixed seed.

Comment: Hi Brian, can you show a screenshot of the experiment setup screen for your freeform setup, i.e. where you say "I choose to vary the parameter in freeform, e.g. surgeLevel: uniform(2,5), surgeDuration: uniform(20,60). ". (This doesn't make sense to me currently so I want to understand what you did there). cheers

Comment: Hi, Benjamin. I just undated my post to include my parameter setup. Thank you for responding to me.

Comment: Alright. What happens if you run a simulation experimentand set surgeLevel=2 and the other "surge...tion" = 20 (i.e. the initial values of the ParamVar setup)? Make sure all other params are as usual and the random seed is the same as where the ParamVar run when it does not finish. My suspicion is that you have some error in the model causing it not to finish